# An adjective for something which satsifies given conditions

Tags: single-word-requests, mathematics

I'm looking for a single-word adjective which means 'satisfies the given conditions'. For example, the condition might be, "Your number must be less than 10." Here the number 2 would be a _____ number. This is specifically in a mathematical context so the surrounding language is somewhat formal.

I thought of *satisfactory* (but it sounds like I'm still not happy with the choice), *suitable* (I've used this word once already so I don't want to repeat it), and *fitting* (doesn't really... fit).

Comment: A remark: rather than "Here the number 2 would be a (valid) number", you would rather write "Here the number 2 would be a (valid) choice". The "number" in itself bears no validity, it is the fact of choosing it for a particular purpose that has. You'll find that with this formulation, many more synonyms of "valid" will be... valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***[Valid](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/valid)***. You are applying a *validation* rule to the supplied candidate; if it passes the test it is *valid*, if not, it is *invalid*

> appropriate to the end in view (Merriam-Webster)

Answer (score 2):

Compliant or consistent or qualifying or requisite

Answer (score 0):

***[Proper](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/proper):***

> - appropriate or suited for some purpose: in its proper place.

Collins

Answer (score 0):

***[applicable](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/applicable)***

> applying or capable of being applied; relevant; suitable; appropriate:
>   an applicable rule; a solution that is applicable to the problem.

Source: dictionary.com